# Heroku error deploy: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my node.js backend, but I can't due to the fact that I get the following error:

[image]

I have found some questions about this, but those questions have not solved my error.

My project is the following:

[image]

And my `package.json` is the following:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js",
    "start": "node ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "generate-password": "^1.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.1",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the **start command** in the package.json file to:

```json
...
"start":"node ./src/index.js"
...
```